# How to return certain fields in array form in Mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework, project, facet

I've list of Books in Mongodb Database. I want to return its **`author`,`brand`,`type`** in `array` or `Any Structure` which Can I used it in my Front End `React` for Creating `Filter`

**Playground**( I've tried ): https://mongoplayground.net/p/eVane4iBN_j

---

**Database Structure:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
    "brand": "Apple",
    "type": "Comedy",
    "author": "Mark",
    "price": 535
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
    "brand": "Mango",
    "type": "Horror",
    "author": "David",
    "price": 695
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
    "brand": "Orange",
    "type": "Horror",
    "author": "Carl",
    "price": 695
  },
  {
    "_id": "4",
    "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
    "brand": "Mango",
    "type": "Horror",
    "author": "Carl",
    "price": 69
  },
  {
    "_id": "5",
    "title": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit",
    "brand": "Orange",
    "type": "Drama",
    "author": "David",
    "price": 695
  }
]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
{
  "brand"  : ["Apple","Mango","Orange"],
  "type"   : ["Horror","Drama","Comedy"],
  "author" : ["David","Mark","Carl"]
}
```

I've tried using **`$project`** to return only `brand`,`type` and `author`

Which Aggeration framework should I use to make this ?? I really need your help guys Please Help Me with this...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$group` and `$addToSet`

- `$group` using as `_id` nothing because you can get anything and `$addToSet` to avoid duplicates.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "",
      "brand": {
        "$addToSet": "$brand"
      },
      "type": {
        "$addToSet": "$type"
      },
      "author": {
        "$addToSet": "$author"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hYyDTSrDmh6)